# Rails Model minitest: "Expected false to be truthy"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I'm having trouble getting an assertion to pass in a RoR minitest. As far as I'm aware, this object should be totally valid. I can add an object with these attributes on the products page, but using the same attributes in a test fails this assertion.

**Model:**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :title, uniqueness: true
    validates :price, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01 }
    validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
        with: %r{​​\.​​(gif|jpg|png)​​\z​​}i,
        message: 'must be GIF, JPG, or PNG'
    }
end
```

**Test in question:**

```
  test "price must be greater than or equal to 0.01" do
    product = Product.new(title: "My Book Title",
      description: "the description",
      image_url: "zzz.jpg")

      product.price = -1
      assert product.invalid?

      product.price = 0
      assert product.invalid?

      product.price = 1
      assert product.valid?
    end
```

The other two assertions pass, but something about the object is still invalid, even after setting a valid price. I also commented out the `validates :price` part, but something is still invalid in the test.

This is also my first foray into Ruby in general, so I may be missing something totally obvious but I've really no idea.

Comment: The important takeaway here should be learning how to debug your code. What is `product.errors.messages`? Staring at a boolean value is not very helpful in diagnosing the root of the problem, but you can print out the full reason as to **why** the product has been deemed "invalid".

Comment: You could do this with a basic `puts` statement or, better, learn how to use a *debugger* such as `binding.irb`, `binding.pry` or `byebug`. Adding this to your project is quite easy -- see [the README](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug).

Comment: Based on what you've shown above, I'm not sure why your `product` is deemed "invalid", either; the first thing I'd do is print out the full error messages to see. In fact, I wouldn't have written a test like that in the first place, because the error message is pretty useless; I'd have tested something like `assert_empty product.errors` instead, so that an error message automatically displays **why** it's "invalid".

Comment: My best guess is that it's because of *something you haven't shown us*. Maybe there's another model validation you haven't mentioned? Maybe you already created another `product` with the same title, and it's complaining about the duplicate record? Or maybe you did something really silly, like forgot to save the file!

Comment: Also -- one last thing: It would be best practice to do **boundary testing** a little more precisely. The critical boundary point is `product.price = 0` and `product.price = 0.01`; yet you're only testing `0` and `1`. Why not `0.01`?

Comment: @TomLord thanks for your useful comments. I will look into what options there are for adding a debugger to my project. I have been doing a little more debugging and found that the invalidity is caused by the regex for image URL. This was confirmed when trying to add a product with "x.jpg/gif/png" on the frontend. Bearing in mind I'm new to Rails and following a book, I've no idea what is going wrong with that regex, but it's definitely that causing the product to be invalid. Also I'll take your point about boundary testing on board as well :)

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so this is really bizarre. I downloaded the products.rb file straight from the book's website, and although the contents were *identical*, the regex worked and all of the assertions passed. I can only assume that there are some rules I was unaware of about whitespace in validates: calls? Because otherwise I have no idea, as the contents of my version and the website's version were exactly the same.

Comment: *the contents of my version and the website's version were exactly the same* -- Clearly not. If you changed absolutely nothing, then the test wouldn't have gone from failing to passing. My suspicion is that you had unsaved changes in the file, and were actually testing a different validation definition.

Comment: Nevertheless, like I said above, the critical takeaway here should be how to debug your failing test :)